# Alerts and error messages forcing dialog box to close

Tags: jquery, html, dialog

I am trying to display alert message ( validation error messages) within a dialog box.

When an alert box is opened it automatically closes the existing opened dialog box. I want to ensure dialog box does not close automatically when errors messages are displayed.

Can anyone please help?

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new category">
        <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
        <form>
            <fieldset>

                <label for="code">Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="code" maxlength="9" id="code" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
                <label for="name">Year</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="4" value=""
                       class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>


    $(function () {

        var new_dialog = function (type, row) {
            var dlg = $("#dialog-form").clone();
            var year = dlg.find(("#acad_year")),
                    code = dlg.find(("#acad_code"));
            type = type || 'Create';
            var config = {
                autoOpen: true,
                height: 300,
                width: 350,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Create Academic Year": function () {
                        save_data("create");
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        dlg.dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                    dlg.remove();
                }
            }; 




            function save_data(strings) {
                var id;
                dlg.dialog("close");
                if (strings == 'edit') {
                    id = $(row.children().get(0)).text();
                } else {
                    id = "NU=L";
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'acad_year.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        from: strings,
                        acad_year: year.val(),
                        acad_code: code.val()
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response[0] === "REDUNDANT") {
                            alert("Data already exists. ");
                        }else if(response[0] === "EMPTY"){

                           alert("Data can't be left empty "); 
                        } else {
                            sortTable(1);
                            $("#acodes tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td style='display:none;'>" + response[1] + "<td>" + year.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + code.val() + "</td>" + "<td><a href='' class='edit'>Edit</a></td>" + "<td><span id='" + response[1] + "' class='delete'><a href=''>Delete</a></span></td>" + "</tr>");

                        }
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("ERROR.." + error[0]);
                    }
                });

            }
        };
```

Comment: use `return false;` just after your `alert` code

Comment: It does not work, dialog box still disappears.